# Laravel get relationship

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a database as follows:

devices
-id
-name

available_params
-id
-name

reportable
-id
-device_id
-available_params_id
-last_value

My query is based on the Device Model which has:

```
    public function reportable()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Reportable::class);
}
```

that works

My Reportable model has:

```
    public function n4sparameter()
{
    return $this->hasMany(AvailableParams::class,'id','available_params_id');
}
```

and thats the part that doesn't work.

```
$device = Device::with(['reportable','reportable.available_params', 'created_by'])->findOrFail($id);
```

I tried hasMany, belongsTo, and a few others in case I had some relationship wrong.

Comment: It should be `reportable.n4sparameter`

Comment: You are right, however, to make it more readable I had renamed the fields... reportable model should have had

public function available_params()
{
    return $this->hasMany(AvailableParams::class,'id','available_params_id');
}

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem was to my question. @m-khalid-junaid you had the right answer to the question... the problem however was because of scopes.

My main Model Devices is scoped by team_id, the 2 consecutive models, reportable and available_params did not have team_id

I simply added:

```
return $this->hasMany(Reportable::class)->withoutGlobalScopes();
```

It works now. Thanks for your feedback